# Jquery child selector explanation

Tags: jquery, html

I have this markup

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

When I select child with jQuery, there are two ways:

```
$("#parent .child")
```

And

```
$("#parent").find(".child")
```

Can someone explain the difference between the two selector and which is the best?

Comment: They are both identical. There's no 'better' version, just whichever suits your needs. The former works when you know both the parent and child selectors. The latter when you already have the parent cached in an object.

Comment: In most cases its better to use `$("#parent").find(".child")` because you will most likely need to use the `$("#parent")`-selector again sometime and can store it in a variable.

Comment: This is probably nitpicking, but that's actually a descendant selector, and `find()` also matches descendants, not only children.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi they both match descendants.

Comment: @misantronic, yup, that's what I said. Maybe my comment isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#parent .child")` & `$("#parent").find(".child")` are same. Both will select all the child elements with class name `child` recursively. ie, it will return the child elements of any level.

If you are using `$("#parent > .child")` it will return the first level children only. This selector is same as `$("#parent").children(".child")`

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two selectors. Both `$("#parent .child")` and `$("#parent").find(".child")` will return the same results (in your example, both `div` elements with the class of `child` within the `div` with id of `parent`.